# python multiprocessing report bug: ran out of input

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am implementing a GUI project, and I want to use `multiprocessing` to accelerate the calculation. In order to tell the user that the calculation is finished, I use a `threading` to check whether the calculation is finished. My code is:

```
import sys
import threading

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import multiprocessing

import time
class SubProcess(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self, calFunc):
        super().__init__()
        self.calFunc = calFunc
        self.recv, self.send = multiprocessing.Pipe(False)

    def run(self) -> None:

        self.calFunc()
        self.send.send(True)

    def IsFinished(self):
        return self.recv.recv()

class SubThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, calFunc, finishFunc):
        super().__init__()
        self.finishFunc = finishFunc

        self.subProcess = SubProcess(calFunc)

    def start(self) -> None:
        super().start()
        self.subProcess.start()

    def run(self) -> None:

        while self.subProcess.IsFinished() != True:
            pass

        self.finishFunc()


class Widget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.btn = QPushButton('calculation')
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.calBtnClick)
        self.label = QLabel('not finish')
        self.lay = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.lay)

        self.lay.addWidget(self.btn)
        self.lay.addWidget(self.label)

    def calBtnClick(self, check=False):
        print('calculation')
        self.subThread = SubThread(self.calculation, self.finish)
        self.subThread.start()

    def finish(self):
        print('calculation finish')
        self.label.setText('finish')

    def calculation(self):
        time.sleep(5)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Widget()
    win.show()
    app.exec()
```

When press the `QPushButton`, I want `Widget.calculation` run in the sub-process, and a sub-threading will check whether the sub-process is finished.

However, the code reports a bug:

```
  
    
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/zhq/Desktop/test/test2.py", line 58, in calBtnClick
    self.subThread.start()
  File "C:/Users/zhq/Desktop/test/test2.py", line 32, in start
    self.subProcess.start()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\MedPro\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 112, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\MedPro\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 223, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\MedPro\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 322, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\MedPro\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 89, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\MedPro\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: can't pickle Widget objects
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\MedPro\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\MedPro\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 115, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

The bug is reported for `self.subProcess.start()`.

How to fix this bug? Any suggestion is appreciated~~~

---

Update

Thank @Dipet, the code is modifed as:

```
import sys
import threading

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import multiprocessing

import time

def calFunc():
    time.sleep(5)

class SubProcess(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self, calFunc):
        super().__init__()
        self.calFunc = calFunc
        self.recv, self.send = multiprocessing.Pipe(False)

    def run(self) -> None:

        self.calFunc()
        self.send.send(True)

    def IsFinished(self):
        return self.recv.recv()

class SubThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, calFunc, finishFunc):
        super().__init__()
        self.finishFunc = finishFunc

        self.subProcess = SubProcess(calFunc)

    def start(self) -> None:
        super().start()
        self.subProcess.start()

    def run(self) -> None:

        while self.subProcess.IsFinished() != True:
            pass

        self.finishFunc()


class Widget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.btn = QPushButton('calculation')
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.calBtnClick)
        self.label = QLabel('not finish')
        self.lay = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.lay)

        self.lay.addWidget(self.btn)
        self.lay.addWidget(self.label)

    def calBtnClick(self, check=False):
        print('calculation')
        self.subThread = SubThread(calFunc, self.finish)
        self.subThread.start()

    def finish(self):
        print('calculation finish')
        self.label.setText('finish')

    def calculation(self):
        time.sleep(5)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Widget()
    win.show()
    app.exec()
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiprocessing module provide args using pickle, so all values that you provided into subproces must support pickle protocol. You use `self.finish` as an argument for your worker, but this is a `Widget` method, but `QWidget` do not support pickling. And you see and error: `TypeError: can't pickle Widget objects`. Try to use staticmethod or common function.